# Django : load a restricted set of fields of objects loaded using a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code, using Django ORM

```
    routes =Routes.objects.filter(scheduleid=schedule.id).only('externalid')
    t_list = [(route.externalid, route.vehicle.name) for route in routes])
```

and it is very slow, because the vehicle objects are huge (dozens of fields, and I cannot change that, it is coming from a legacy database). A lot of time is devoted to create the Vehicle objects, while I only need the name field of this object.

Is there a more efficient way to obtain t_list ? I am looking for something like only() for accessing objects through a foreign key.

EDIT : 
the solution is the following :

```
routes=Routes.objects.filter(scheduleid=schedule.id).select_related("vehicle")
routes= routes.only('externalid','vehicle__name')
```

Does there exist something similar ?

Comment: select_related might be a very bad choice, because it get all related foreignkey related fields. If you do not define a depth and vehicle table have to many foreignkeys, execution time of the query will be greater.

Comment: @FallenAngel: the OP is limiting the scope of `select_related()` to `Vehicle`. i.e. `select_related('vehicle')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this, I think. <strike>Warning: not tested</strike> Tested using local models. Generated query looked good.

```
routes = Routes.objects.select_related('vehicle').filter(**conditions).only(
            'externalid', 'vehicle__name')
```

For this to work there should be a `vehicle` foreign key field declared in `Routes` model. This is 'cause `select_related()` only follows *forward* relationships.

Comment: It works. I thought I had tried this before, but apparently, I must have made a mistake. I have checked that the sql queries are fetching just what is needed. Thanks !

Comment: BTW, in fact, your code is equivalent to my "ideal code" .... My question was self answered. Sorry ...

Comment: @madewulf: don't be! Writing the question out crystallizes thought. And in the process we often figure out the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
Routes.objects.filter(scheduleid__id=schedule.id).values('externalid', 'vehicle__name')
```